# Easy slider1.7 issue add extra <li> when i am using only one <li>

Tags: easyslider

Please help me when i am using easy slider jquery1.7 with one image like

- 

its added two more

one is before my

and another is after

how to resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the continuous option? 
I have found this is an issue when you specify continuous.
The solution I have used is to edit the easyslider1.7.js file at line no 74  if (options.continuous) {
and comment out from there through to 78 at the end of the if clause.

I have let this run and found that this does not seem to affect the continuous flow of the slider.
Hope this helps.

Edit:
On running for a while I have discovered that removing those lines does affect the flow slightly, the first image always look as if it is dropped in if continuous is set to true.
If you only have the one image though this shouldn't be a problem for you though.